# TFS2013 build error

Tags: tfs, build, build-definition

I created a build definition with a customized xaml file. When triggering the build, getting the error message

> TF14045: The identity Build Agent is not a recognized identity.

The build is successful when we used default template.

How to fix this issue.

Comment: What are the customizations you've made?

Comment: Could you share more detailed info? Such as more info of related logs, how did you custom your xaml file, did some of the customization related to the build agent ? An error ID can't narrow down the issue.